Why does forward CG decrease controllability/maneuvarability?
Why is a larger elevator input required to change the pitch of an aircraft with a more forward CG? I would think intuitively that the farther forward the CG, the greater the arm between the elevator and the CG, and therefore the greater the moment.
Thank you

Intuitively:  the farther forward from the center of lift that the CG is, the greater the "lever arm" that inertia has in keeping the airplane doing what it's trimmed for.  That effect overwhelms the slight increase in distance from CG to elevator.  For a typical small airplane, moving the CG forwards by a foot might double the lever arm of inertia, but increase by only a few per cent the lever arm of the elevator.
